# c++ derived class accessing base class' friend operators

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, iostream, friend

I am working with operator overloading and inheritance. I currently have something similar to the following code:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, derived& d)
{
   /* Some code asking for input to populate the object's data members*/
   cin >> d; /*Here, the operator called is this one, creating an infinite loop*/
}
```

The base class has an istream >> operator and when trying to invoke it, the operator actually calls itself, causing a loop. How can I access the base's operator from the derived's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to the base class to call the `operator>>` on base class, otherwise it would try to call itself and lead to infinite recursion. E.g.

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, derived& d)
{
    in >> static_cast<base&>(d);
    return in;
}
```

PS: You should use `in` instead of using `cin` fixedly, and return `in` in `operator>>`.

Comment: @OP, ever wonder why we need to return the object even though you've passed it with reference? (That's just something for you to ponder on ;) )

Comment: I knew it had something to do with type conversion, thank you! Will this change the object's type permanently? Meaning that I would have to convert it back to its derived class? Or will it be a temporary change?

@d4rk4ng31 Interesting... Is it because it has changed?

Comment: @Diego, Learn about lvalues and rvalues in C++... a hint, `static_cast<base&>(d)` is an rvalue, which you recognise, the moment you ctrl+click and it takes you to the function it actually calls.

Comment: Also, no, your guess is wrong. We return it for chaining purposes

Comment: @Diego You don't need to convert it back. The conversion just takes effect in the statement `in >> static_cast<base&>(d);`.